# Linux-based instant replay solution?

Tags: linux, video

I've been tasked with building a Linux-based instant replay machine for my University's athletics department.  Output from this machine will potentially be broadcast, not just viewed by referees/coaches.  Video output should look and behave as much like tape as possible; in particular I need frame-by-frame forward and reverse playback.  I also need the ability to set and return to bookmarks in a live video stream.

I've made a start with MythTV, but its frame-by-frame behaviour for reverse playback leaves something to be desired.  Reading the FAQ for MPlayer, it doesn't look as though frame-by-frame reverse playback is currently implemented, nor is it likely to be implemented in the near future.  It doesn't look as though FFMpeg or avisynth will work in real time.

Avidemux seems to have a lot of the features I'm looking for, especially when it comes to frame-by-frame behaviour.  Unfortunately, I know of no way to output avidemux's video separate from the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely one of those instances where trying to homebrew a solution is penny wise, but pound foolish.

Users of this system will not be tolerant of any issues with it, and do you really want to be dealing with the director of athletics when your system breaks?

There are many well-supported, well-integrated commercial solutions that do this - the university's money would be well spent on one of them.